# About nodes number on Flink

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-flink

I'm developing a Flink toy-application on my local machine before to deploy the real one on a real cluster. 
Now I have to determine how many nodes I need to set the cluster.

But I'm still a bit confused about how many nodes I have to consider to execute my application.

For example if I have the following code (from the doc):

```
DataStream<String> lines = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>()...);

DataStream<Event> events = lines.map((line)->parse(line));

DataStream<Statistics> stats = events
        .keyBy("id");
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
        .apply(new MyWindowAggregationFunction());

stats.addSink(new RollingSink(path));
```

- This means that operations "on same line" are executed on same node? (It sounds a bit strange to me)

Some confirms:

- If the answer to previous question is yes and if I set parallelism to 1 I can establish how many nodes I need counting how many operations I have to perform ?
- If I set parallelism to N but I have less than N nodes available Flink automatically scales the elaboration on available nodes?

My throughput and data load are not relevant I think, it is not heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, I recommend reading https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/concepts/runtime.html, which explains how the Flink runtime is organized.

Each task manager (worker node) has some number of task slots (at least one), and a Flink cluster needs exactly as many task slots as the highest parallelism used in the job. So if the entire job has a parallelism of one, then a single node is sufficient. If the parallelism is N and fewer than N task slots are available, the job can't be executed.

The Flink community is working on dynamic rescaling, but as of version 1.3, it's not yet available.

Comment: Ok but, for instance, look at the image:
https://ibb.co/dCYVHk
 I'd like to build a pipeline like this, where each circle represents a different physical node. In my mind I have parallelism '1' and the cluster is a group of pipeline like in the image (also because I have an unbounded stream so I prefer if each node has to perform just fast operation (real-time) to avoid to create long queue)

Comment: Flink has the flexibility to be configured in the manner you describe. You can arrange to have multiple CPUs available per slot, and you are also able to control the grouping of operators into slots via task chaining and resource groups (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/datastream_api.html#task-chaining-and-resource-groups).